# (Editing Angular 5) I can't get the values of the object that is in NgModel

Tags: angular, forms, angular5, angular2-ngmodel

I could not get the object of this field

component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="totalPrice" class="form-control" #lastname="ngModel"[(ngModel)]="invoiceService.selectedInvoice.totalPrice" readonly>
</div> <!-- working ok -->
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" name="purchases" class="form-control" #purchases="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="invoiceService.selectedInvoice.purchases['product']" readonly>
</div><!-- not working -->
```

this the element

[image]

Any idea?

here's an example `(login => user:user@user.com | pass: user123)` [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hhhc87?embed=1&file=src/app/components/invoices/invoice-list/invoice-list.component.html)

Comment: If `purchases` is an array, then you will need to specify which `purchase` you want to update (e.g. the first one, the second one, etc)

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to have an input field for every purchases' price?

Comment: get the values of the item that I select to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this was the solution. It does not work because i use two way binding NgModel which binds incoming value to the same variable - i.product.name

```
<ng-template ngFor let-i [ngForOf]="invoiceService.selectedInvoice.purchases"> 
    {{i.product.name | json}}   
    <input type="text" name="purchases" class="form-control" [value]="i.product.name" readonly>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understand your problem properly.

With this part `invoiceService.selectedInvoice.purchases['product']` you're trying to access one of the array entries, which are of type `product` i think.

To access every entry of your `purchases` array you need to do something like this for every array entry, but this is not recommended:

```
[(ngModel)]="invoiceService.selectedInvoice.purchases[0]" // get the first product (first entry of the array), etc.
```

But the index would be hard coded, which is as I said not recommend.

So you should do following:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let product of invoiceService.selectedInvoice.purchases">

    <!-- Creates an input field for every product's price -->
    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="product.price" readonly>

    <!-- Print the product object as json -->
    {{prodcut | json}} 
</div>
```

If you're not familiar with `*ngFor` see [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

Comment: purchases could be multiple products, so I always need a loop to get the values. maybe I need a multiple select element to show those obtained values, but what is happening is that I can not get to "price" when I associate them with my Ngmodel